# Как переустановить Page Ruler Redux после удаления из магазина расширений?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

Перестало работать расширение для Chrome Page Ruler Redux (линейка). Он пропал из магазина расширений, при попытке установить из GitHub - едет CSS плагина. Решение найдено. Как сделать так, чтобы Page Ruler заработал?

Answer (score 1):

1. Скачиваем расширение по ссылке https://github.com/Esteban-Rocha/page-ruler-redux
2. Распаковываем в любое место. Обратите внимание, что после установки эта папка должна оставаться по данному пути. Удалив её, расширение перестанет работать, поэтому подумайте над путем распаковки заранее
3. В папке `путь_к_папке\page-ruler-redux-master\src` создаем файл `content.css`, в него копируем содержимое `путь_к_папке\page-ruler-redux-master\src\sass\base\_legacy.scss`
4. Устанавливаем расширение, заходим в Управление расширениями -> Ставим галочку на "Режим разработчика" в верхнем углу -> Загрузить упакованное расширение -> Выбираем папку `путь_к_папке\page-ruler-redux-master\src`

5. Наслаждаемся крутым расширением. Единственное, что я сделал - добавил для #page-ruler-toolbar `font-family:Arial`, чтобы расширение не брало нативный шрифт текущего сайта

Эх, потратил ночь, чтобы разобраться. Чтож, сэкономлю время вам! Успехов!